# how do I extract string in between "Rolename": and ,

Tags: python, regex

I have a `json object` that contains this :

```
"RoleName": "sf-community-apple", "RoleId": "AROAI12345678954",
```

how would I extract `sf-community-apple`, from the above string? I would really appreciate the help. Thanks

Comment: Time to eplore json module https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: A wise man once said: "Before using regex you have one problem but once you use it you'll have many more".